# Do plants feel emotional pain as humans and animals do?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, neuropsychology

I have a question in mind regarding about plants. I remember there is an experiment where plants raised in good environment with compliments tends to flourish and grows bigger compare to the plants raise in a bad environment. Which leads me to ponder on the question whether do plants feel's emotions  the same way as humans do even though they do not have any means of expressing it.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  Do you remember the details of the experiment you mentioned? (Authors and name of paper).

Comment: For me, there is a big difference between "feel" and "feel emotions." I believe, emotions can be felt only in the heart. So, if a plant does not have a heart, it can't feel emotions. But it may still feel something what makes it respond in a certain way, rather than experience something as pleasant or not.

Comment: That plants raised in a good environment with compliments tend to flourish and grows bigger compared to the plants raised in a bad environment doesn’t mean that they have feelings. First, there might be some other factors related to the compliments given to them, such as better, or more frequent, or biased care, that make them flourish and grow better. And, even if the experiments are well designed and really prove that compliments help plants flourish and grow better, they still do not prove that plants have feelings; they just prove only that compliments help plants flourish and grow better.

Comment: About feelings or emotion in plants. Physically considering, to date, there is no evidence for them. Physically considering, feelings and emotion are phenomena that are dynamic and have specific characteristics of their own. For plants to have feelings or emotion, plants must have some phenomena in them that are similarly dynamic and have similarly specific characteristics. In animals, neural signaling in their brains have these kinds of dynamics and specificity. But in plants, to date, no phenomena that have these kinds of dynamics and specificity have been found yet.